# Junit5 Duplicated parameter in parameterized test

Tags: java, junit5

I have a function that takes in two objects and returns the "largest" one. For the purpose of this question the determination of "largest" is not important. I have a parameterized test that looks like the following:

```
@ParameterizedTest()
@MethodSource
void testGetLargest(Widget widget1, Widget widget2, Widget expectedLargestWidget) {
   var largestWidget = service.getLargestWidget(widget1, widget2);

   assertEquals(expectedLargestWidget, largestWidget);
}

private static Stream<Arguments> testGetLargest() {
    return Stream.of(
            Arguments.of(
                    Widget.builder().field1("something").field2("something else").build(),
                    Widget.builder().field1("second something").field2("second something else").build(),
                    **not sure what to put here**),
                    ...
```

As you can see, the third parameter for the test should be the same as one of the first two. While I could copy the code and make a third argument which is the same as one of the first two, this feels messy.

Is there a way to either build the arguments in a way that I can pass the same object as one of the first two as the third parameter?

Or that in my test, I can reference one of the existing params as the third one?
I have considered having the third param be an int that represents index for one of the first two and then using reflection but this also feels heavy.

Comment: Change your test to take an array, and then pass the index to the largest widget?

Comment: Passing an integer as third parameter is fine, but it will give you lots of pain when trying to actually assert if first object is greater or second (since you will have to compare object with integer), as a general practice it is better to pass the entire object and check for its equality during the assert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a case where a fresh look the next day lead to a very obvious answer. I updated my methodSource function to first build the objects and then pass references to them and this allowed me to reuse the reference to the largest widget.

```
private static Stream<Arguments> testGetLargest() {
   Widget widget1 = Widget.builder().field1("something").field2("something else").build();
   Widget widget2 = Widget.builder().field1("second something").field2("second something else").build();
    return Stream.of(
            Arguments.of(
                    widget1,
                    widget2,
                    widget1),
                    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you kind of over thought it, since you know which one should be the largest one, you can always put the expected one as the **first parameter**, then compare `largestWidget` with it, you would only need two parameters :

```
@ParameterizedTest()
@MethodSource
void testGetLargest(Widget widget1, Widget widget2) {
   var largestWidget = service.getLargestWidget(widget1, widget2);

   assertEquals(widget1, largestWidget);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Qiu, your answer works very well for my example however it was a simplified version of my actual problem. For my actual problem I was taking in two objects that were not of the exact same type and so I did not have flexibility to change first param. I was also looking for a way to pass in the same value twice and thus I could not mark your solution as the answer.

Comment: @ssc327 That's okay, you should always accept the answer that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `@MethodSource` you can try `@CsvSource`.
I did this when I needed 3 Integer parameters in one parameterized test.
Here is the signature of my test method:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource("300,10,", "150,5,", "90,9,0", "100,0,10")
fun totalScoreTests(result: Int, firstThrow: Int, secondThrow: Int?)
```

It is Kotlin instead of Java, but JUnit 5 is usable in both languages.
You can find my full example in this blog post, if you search for "GameTest":
https://agile-coding.blogspot.com/2021/06/clean-code-dojo.html

Comment: Thank you but this will not work since I am building complex objects